# Install gcc on AWS EC2 without using yum?

Tags: linux, gcc, amazon-ec2, redis

I am trying to install Redis on EC2 but it needs gcc. When I tried gcc was not installed.

Then I tried to install gcc manually and got the following error:

> configure: error: could not find a working compiler, see config.log for details

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 28):

If you use a standard AMI Linux instance, you can install gcc simply by running:

```
sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
```

On a SuSE instance, you can try:

```
sudo zypper install gcc
```

Comment: My linux version is : Linux ip-XXXXXXXX x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Thanks!! The Linux machine is SUSE Linux.

Comment: Getting authentication error: Authentication required for 'http://smt-ec2.susecloud.net/repo/SUSE/Updates/SLE-Module-Adv-Systems-Management/12/x86_64/update?credentials=SMT-http_smt-ec2_susecloud_net'

Answer (score 1):

I copied form [user7706975's answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/923337/789450)

1 Download gcc version from gcc.parentingamerica.com/releases.

2 Compile it from [Gcc Wiki](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC) for example if you want the version 4.6.2

```
tar xzf gcc-4.6.2.tar.gz
cd gcc-4.6.2
./contrib/download_prerequisites
cd ..
mkdir objdir
cd objdir
$PWD/../gcc-4.6.2/configure --prefix=$HOME/GCC-4.6.2 --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,go
make
make install
```

Reference: My AWS EC2 Instance: Ubuntu 16.04